# Mysql Simple Query Takes Too Long To Execute

Tags: mysql

I have a query and it seems very slow

**My Problem**

```
select conversation_hash as search_hash 
from conversation 
where conversation_hash ='xxxxx' 
and result_published_at between '1600064000' and '1610668799'  
order by result_published_at desc 
limit 5
```

There is a total of `773179` Records when I run

```
select count(*) 
from conversation 
where conversation_hash ='xxxxx'
```

After I do an explain query

```
explain select conversation_hash as search_hash 
        from conversation 
        where conversation_hash ='xxxxx' 
        and result_published_at between '1600064000' and '1610668799'  
        order by result_published_at desc 
        limit 5
```

i got this

```
id,select_type,table,partitions,type,possible_keys,key,key_len,ref,rows,filtered,extra 
1, SIMPLE, conversation, , range, idx_result_published_at,conversation_hash_channel_content_id_index,conversation_result_published_at_index,virtaul_ad_id_conversation_hash, idx_result_published_at, 5, , 29383288, 1.79, Using index condition;Using where
```

**Possible Issues**

- By looking in the explain query I can see it return more
  rows(29383288) than the total Records (ie 773179)
- key_len is 5. result_published_at is a timestamp field and its length
  is def more than 5 eg(1625836640)

What can I improve to make this query Fast, Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Indexes for conversation

```
Table,Non_unique,Key_name,Seq_in_index,Column_name,Collation,Cardinality,Sub_part,Packed,Null,Index_type,Comment,Index_comment
conversation,0,PRIMARY,1,id,A,96901872,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,0,conversation_conversation_hash_id_result_id_unique,1,conversation_hash_id,A,240485,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,0,conversation_conversation_hash_id_result_id_unique,2,result_id,A,100693480,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,0,conversation_conversation_hash_id_channel_content_id_unique,1,conversation_hash_id,A,232122,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,0,conversation_conversation_hash_id_channel_content_id_unique,2,channel_content_id,A,100693480,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,1,conversation_tool_id_foreign,1,tool_id,A,7788,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,1,idx_result_published_at,1,result_published_at,A,38164712,NULL,NULL,YES,BTREE,,
conversation,1,idx_user_name,1,user_name,A,10896208,NULL,NULL,YES,BTREE,,
conversation,1,conversation_hash_channel_content_id_index,1,conversation_hash,A,294048,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,1,conversation_hash_channel_content_id_index,2,channel_content_id,A,99699696,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,1,idx_parent_channel_content_id,1,parent_channel_content_id,A,3550741,NULL,NULL,YES,BTREE,,
conversation,1,idx_channel_content_id,1,channel_content_id,A,90350472,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,1,conversation_result_published_at_index,1,result_published_at,A,37177476,NULL,NULL,YES,BTREE,,
conversation,1,virtaul_ad_id_conversation_hash,1,conversation_hash,A,238906,NULL,NULL,,BTREE,,
conversation,1,virtaul_ad_id_conversation_hash,2,virtual_ad_id,A,230779,NULL,NULL,YES,BTREE,,
conversation,1,idx_ad_story_id,1,ad_story_id,A,167269,NULL,NULL,YES,BTREE,,
```

Comment: can you share your create table for conversation

Comment: Try moving `result_published_at` to where condition and `conversation_hash ='xxxxx'` to the and condition

Comment: Add the output of  `show create table conversation `

Comment: `and result_published_at between '1600064000' and '1610668799' ` Are you really storing these as strings?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Is Mysql really that awful at query optimization that switching the order of where predicates would cause different behavior? I'm not a big fan of mysql, but I think better of it than that.

Comment: @ErgestBasha it's too big to paste here

Comment: @JNevill changing the order of result_published_at didn't help

Comment: @JNevill result published at is integer

Comment: Total shot in the dark. I expect better of mysql so I don't suspect this will help, but I've seen it happen on other RDBMS's that they will perform an implicit casts of a column in a where predicate if the literals supplied in the condition are of a different type. At any rate, try dropping the single quotes around your result_published_at condition. `and result_published_at between 1600064000 and 1610668799`

Comment: @JNevill added show create table conversation in question please see

Comment: @JNevill already remove single quotes and still slow

Comment: Figured as much. I'll scratch that from my mental list of possible gotcha's for mysql.

Comment: @JNevill sometimes it happens to me that putting the date column in the where clause , or as the first condition , having an index on date performs much faster.

Comment: @professor you don't have an index on `result_published_at`

Comment: @ErgestBasha already  added in my question

Comment: @professor I suggest to use  proper date format on `result_published_at` and add an index

Comment: @ErgestBasha yes, already have an index,i know the above snippet doesn't have,because i take it from my local

Comment: @ErgestBasha updated question,please see indexes

Comment: That's interesting (regarding ordering) @ErgestBasha. I will keep in mind.

Comment: `SELECT x WHERE x=constant` -- seems useless; you know the value of x??

Comment: @JNevill - Quoting (or not) an integer constant has no impact on how a query is processed.  The one case where it does matter is when comparing a varchar to an unquoted integer  Indexing the varchar won't help because it converts the varchar to numeric to perform the comparision.

Comment: @ErgestBasha - Think "composite index".

Comment: @RickJames yes that will make a difference. I can see same indexes twice, like `result_published_at`, which are not needed .

Comment: @professor Your FIRST EXPLAIN did NOT return 29383288 rows. It EXAMINED 29383288 rows. The next column tells you it RETURNED 1.79% of those rows. Please POST from your PRODUCTION system, TEXT results with DATE/TIME your current A) Query, B) EXPLAIN SELECT sql_no_cache (rest of your query); C) SHOW TABLE STATUS conversation; and D) SHOW CREATE TABLE conversation; for current analysis of your request please.

Answer (score 0):

Query is correct, it seems you have to update server configurations for mysql, which is probably not available on a shared hosting environment. However, if you have your own server the follow these steps:

1. Go to `my.cnf` file, in my case it is hosted at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
2. Increate the values of `query_cache_size`, `max_connection`, `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, `innodb_io_capacity`
3. Switch from `MyISAM` to `InnoDB` (if possible)
4. Use latest MySQL version (if possible)

You can get more help from this article https://phoenixnap.com/kb/improve-mysql-performance-tuning-optimization

Comment: we are not using shared hosting

Comment: Please share more details. What makes you think that this change resolve the given problem? Keep in mind that a good explanation helps others to learn from your answer

Comment: This is all related to configurations of resources used by MySQL. I was facing the same problem few years back and implement all these things in that system. This helps me a lot to make query faster but for best performance on front-end we had to move to dynamo db which was synced with mysql

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to read the output of the Explain command because the `possible_keys` output is separated by commas.

Depending on the data access patterns, you might want to create a unique index on `conversation_hash`, in case rows are unique.

If `conversation_hash` is not a unique field you can create a compound index on `conversation_hash, result_published_at` so your query will be fulfilled from the index itself.

Answer (score 0):

`EXPLAIN` *estimates* the row counts.  (It has no way to get the exact number of rows without actually running the query.)  That estimate may be a lot lower or higher than the real count.  It is rare for the estimate to be that far off, but I would not be worried, just annoyed.

The existence of Text and Blob columns sometimes adds to the imprecision of Explain.

Key_len:

- The raw length, which is 5 for `TIMESTAMP` (more below).
- +1 for if `NULL` (+0 for `NOT NULL`).
- Not very useful for `VARCHAR`.

In older versions of MySQL, a Timestamp took 4 bytes and a DATETIME took 8.  When fractional seconds were added, those numbers were changed to 5 in both cases.  This allowed for a "length" to indicate the number of decimal places.   And Datetime was changed from packed decimal to an integer.

Suggest you run `ANALYZE TABLE`.  This might improve the underlying statistics that feed into the estimates.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it may give more insight.

The 'composite' `INDEX(conversation_hash, result_published_at)`, in that order, is optimal for that query.